# Should I keep the feature branches or delete them after merge them into release?

Tags: git

My git working-flow is like this:

```
1. make new feature branch from branch release.
2. developing on it, after finish it, merge it into branch testing
3. Do test with code of branch testing
4. If test passed, merge new feature branch into branch release.
```

But I got a confusion here, should I delete this new feature branch after merge it into release? Why?

Comment: That’s completely up to you. If you think you would want to use those branches again, keep them. Otherwise, since branches are just pointers, there is not much harm in deleting them, especially since they have been merged. You could always “go back” and recreate a branch. But it’s really your choice to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're aware that the decision here is based on preference, I'll share mine.

Delete the branch, because:

1. Branches don't tell your dev story, Pull Requests do
2. It gives a clearer view of your development status
3. Old branches inevitably become stale old branches that you'll have to purge later for 1 and 2

I appreciate how [Atlassian's Git Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-branch) explains it:

> Once the release is ready to ship, Mary merges it into master and
>   develop, then deletes the release branch. It’s important to merge back
>   into develop because critical updates may have been added to the
>   release branch and they need to be accessible to new features. Again,
>   if Mary’s organization stresses code review, this would be an ideal
>   place for a pull request.

Whether you subscribe to [Git Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/) or another methodology, I stand by deleting the branch.

Comment: I agree, the updated git flow tools delete both remote and local branch after merge.